# React creating dynamically refs with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I have a `table` list where each row has a `menu` button, for which I need a `ref`. I am using react mui in my project and it's [menu](https://v4-0-2.material-ui.com/components/menus/). I have tried creating the refs like this:

```
const {rows} = props;
const refs = Array.from({length: rows.length}, a => React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null));
```

And then tried to use the inside the `map` function like this on each `button`:

```
<Button
   ref={refs[index]}
   aria-controls="menu-list-grow"
   aria-haspopup="true"
   onClick={() => handleToggle(row.id)}
>Velg
</Button>
  <Popper open={!!checkIfOpen(row.id)} anchorEl={refs[index].current} keepMounted transition disablePortal>
    {({TransitionProps, placement}) => (
       <Grow
        {...TransitionProps}
        style={{transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom'}}>
       <Paper id="menu-list-grow">
         <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={(e) => handleClose(e, refs[index].current)}>
          <MenuList>                                                        
            <MenuItem
             onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs[index].current)}>Profile</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs[index].current)}>My account</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs[index].current)}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </Paper>
  </Grow>
 )}
</Popper>
```

But, then I get an error:

> React Hook "React.useRef" cannot be called inside a callback. React
>   Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React
>   Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

How can I do this dynamically, so that I can use refs inside the map function. I have tried with the suggestion in the answers, but I couldn't get it to work.
Here is the [codesandbox of the example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-hawking-qy64c).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How target DOM with react useRef in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940399/how-target-dom-with-react-useref-in-map)

Comment: @skyboyer this one is more Typescript oriented

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`useRef` is not exactly the same as React.createRef.
it's better to call it `useInstanceField` :)

So, your code could be a bit another.

First step: we use `useRef` to save the array of refs:

```
const {rows} = props;
const refs = useRef(Array.from({length: rows.length}, a => React.createRef()));
```

Then, in your map function we save each ref to its index in the refs array:

```
<Button
   ref={refs.current[index]}
   aria-controls="menu-list-grow"
   aria-haspopup="true"
   onClick={() => handleToggle(row.id)}
>Velg
</Button>
  <Popper open={!!checkIfOpen(row.id)} anchorEl={refs.current[index].current} keepMounted transition disablePortal>
    {({TransitionProps, placement}) => (
       <Grow
        {...TransitionProps}
        style={{transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom'}}>
       <Paper id="menu-list-grow">
         <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index].current)}>
          <MenuList>                                                        
            <MenuItem
             onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index].current)}>Profile</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index].current)}>My account</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index].current)}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </Paper>
  </Grow>
 )}
</Popper>
```

if your length is changed, you should process it in `useEffect` to change the length of refs

You also can use another way:

1) Create an array of refs, but without React.createRef:

```
const {rows} = props;
const refs = useRef(new Array(rows.length));
```

In map we use `ref={el => refs.current[index] = el}` to store ref

```
<Button
   ref={el => refs.current[index] = el}
   aria-controls="menu-list-grow"
   aria-haspopup="true"
   onClick={() => handleToggle(row.id)}
>Velg
</Button>
  <Popper open={!!checkIfOpen(row.id)} anchorEl={refs.current[index].current} keepMounted transition disablePortal>
    {({TransitionProps, placement}) => (
       <Grow
        {...TransitionProps}
        style={{transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom'}}>
       <Paper id="menu-list-grow">
         <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index])}>
          <MenuList>                                                        
            <MenuItem
             onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index])}>Profile</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index])}>My account</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleClose(e, refs.current[index])}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </Paper>
  </Grow>
 )}
</Popper>
```

Comment: I can't compile this, I get Typescript error: ```Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.```  for this line: ```React.createRef(null) ```

Comment: Sorry, yes, just remove null argument :)
I've updated the answer

Comment: I have done that as well, but then I get: ```Type 'RefObject<{}>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'.```

Comment: It seems typescript doesn't allow to use such way. So I've made an example of this case with TypeScript https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-goldstine-33nw5

Comment: I tried to implement your solution into my example, but then I get the error: ```Type 'HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'.``` And if I change refs to this: ```const refs = React.useRef<Array<React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null>>([]);```, then I get error: ```Type 'HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null'.
  Property 'current' is missing in type 'HTMLButtonElement' but required in type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'```

Comment: yes, I have added it to the question as well, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-hawking-qy64c

Comment: I've fixed types of useRef in your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-meadow-fdpfe
`const refs = React.useRef<Array<HTMLButtonElement | null>>([]);`

Comment: I have done the same, but the popper with the menu is still not working, it seems as it can't recognize to which button the ref refers to.

Comment: It wasn't the problem with `useRef`. I've just removed `keepMounted` prop from popper component: check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-meadow-fdpfe

Answer (score 15):

Here another option:

```
const textInputRefs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([])

...

const onClickFocus = (event: React.BaseSyntheticEvent, index: number) => {
    textInputRefs.current[index]?.focus()
};

...
{items.map((item, index) => (
    <textInput
        inputRef={(ref) => textInputRefs.current[index] = ref}
    />
    <Button
        onClick={event => onClickFocus(event, index)}
    />
}
```

Comment: I believe there's a typo, probably it should be `textInputRefs` and not `textInputs`