# How to get exact DOM element using useRef in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, react-hooks

I am trying to get the exact DOM element in the ListItem of List using 'React.useRef(null);' but not able to get it, i am using below code

```
  useEffect(() => {
   //This is where i am trying to get the exact DOM element
   console.log("listRef", listRef.current);
 }, [searchText]);
```

Here is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cvt4f?file=/demo.tsx:4889-4924)

How to get exact DOM element and what am i missing?

Comment: What do you mean exact DOM element? You are getting the component.

Comment: @SILENT I need the exact DOM element of the ListItem, after that want to add `  listRef.current && listRef.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest"})` to scroll to that one. Do you want me to add the scroll code also to the codesandbox link

Comment: Check this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940399/how-target-dom-with-react-useref-in-map

Comment: Your current implementation is referring to the last element. Do you only want to scroll to the last element or any element on the list?

Comment: @SILENT Yes, exactly that is the issue. I do not want to scroll to last element instead want to scroll to element which contains the first occurrence of searchText entered in searchBar.

Comment: Create an array of refs :   ```const listRef = Array.from({ length: messages.length }, (a) => useRef(null)); ``` . And use this : ```listRef[6].current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest"});``` You need to add the code to search the searchText in the refList array.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Could you please update it in sandbox! Thanks

Comment: Check this the id is hardcoded yet though : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bm4pl?file=/demo.tsx:5093-5172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the code :

Declare the refs array :

```
const listRef =  React.useMemo(() => messages.map(() => React.createRef()), []);
```

Update your useEffect code as below:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    //This is where i am trying to get the exact DOM element
    let index = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      if (
        messages[i].primary.includes(searchText) ||
        messages[i].secondary.includes(searchText)
      ) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    
       listRef[index+1].current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "nearest"
      });
  }, [searchText]);
```

Working code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bm4pl?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Thanks so much Harman, i am trying to implement it in my solution, will accept as answer once it works. Thanks again

Comment: Why am i getting `React Hook "useRef" cannot be called inside a callback` at `const listRef = Array.from({ length: messages.length }, () => useRef(null));`

Comment: You need to change this also : ```<ListItemText  ref={listRef[id]} primary={primary} secondary={secondary} /> </ListItem>``` . Also useRef from react at top where you have imported useEffect

Comment: I did that and not getting error there but at this line `const listRef = Array.from({ length: messages.length }, () => useRef(null));`

Answer (score 2):

Change your useRef to

```
const listRef = useMemo(() => messages.map(() => React.createRef<HTMLElement>()), [])
```

For each list item, set

```
ref={listRef[id]}
```

Call the respective item to scroll to using

```
listRef && listRef[id] && listRef[id].current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest"});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-message-search-0x04c?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Thanks so much, Could you please update my sandbox, since i am using typescript, `const listRef = React.useRef({})` is giving error there. Thanks

Comment: Typescript type is probably `{ [key: number]: HTMLElement}` . Updated and added codesandbox link

Comment: @Thanks for sharing the codesandbox link but unfortunately scroll is yet not working. Is something missed?

Comment: @Lara Oops, sorry. Forgot createRef part. Updated