# useRef is not getting populated with arrayLength

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

I have below code in TypeScript in which i am trying to use `useRef` and assign the arrayLength

```
const listRef = useRef(Array.from({ length: message.length }, a => React.createRef()));
```

but it never gets populated with arrayLength and comes as

> ListRef
> Object
> current: []

Whats's wrong in the code? Why it never takes array value?

Comment: DId my previous answer not work? `const listRef = useMemo(() => messages.map(() => React.createRef<HTMLElement>()), [])` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451730/how-to-get-exact-dom-element-using-useref-in-react/63452156?noredirect=1#answer-63452156

Comment: @SILENT, nope, its giving `TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined`

Comment: @SILENT getting error as `expecting 0 argument but got `1`'

Comment: My bad. Not a Typescript expert.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've told us, the only explanation is that `message.length` as of the **first** call to `useRef` is `0`. Subsequent calls to `useRef` after that (e.g., when the component is re-rendered) will ignore the initial value you pass in, instead returning the ref created by the first call to `useRef`.

Here's a simple example showing that happening:

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect } = React;

function Example({message}) {
    console.log(`Component rendered, message.length = ${message.length}`);
    const listRef = useRef(Array.from({ length: message.length }, a => React.createRef()));
    console.log(`Component rendered, listRef.current.length = ${listRef.current && listRef.current.length}`);
    
    return <div>x</div>;
}

function Parent() {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState<([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setMessage([1, 2, 3]);
        }, 800);
    }, []);
    
    return <Example message={message} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**If** the goal is to expand/contract the array of refs to match `message`, you have to do that explicitly. I **wouldn't** use an array for it, I'd use a `Map`, keyed by some unique information about the entry in `message` that the ref will be used for. That way, the code isn't confused when things are inserted at the beginning of `message`, or in the middle, or when things are rearranged. That might look something like:

```
const {current: messageRefs} = useRef<Map<someType, React.RefObject<HTMLElement>>(new Map());
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                 \
//                                                  −− this part is TypeScript-
//                                                     specific; update the
//                                                     `someType` part to match
//                                                     the type of the unique
//                                                     information you're using,
//                                                     and the `HTMLElement` part
//                                                     to match the type of
//                                                     element you're storing in
//                                                     the ref
for (const {id} of message) {
    if (!messageRefs.get(id)) {
        messageRefs.set(id, React.createRef());
    }
}
```

...and then using them:

```
{message.map(entry => <whatever ref={messageRefs.get(entry.id)}>...</whatever>)}
```

Comment: @Lara - That depends on what you're trying to accomplish...?

Comment: @Lara - I've taken a swing at what I think you may be trying to do, but...